# Where can I find the specification about the upcoming i3 Skylake processors?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i3

I saw that i3-6100, i3-6200, i3-6300, i3-6320 ... is coming in September, but no more details about it. Where can I find more information (frequency, cache, hyperthreading, ...)?

Comment: If you can't find it online, than it probably hasn't been released yet.

Comment: When this information is released it will be on Intel's website.

Comment: It is interesting that you can find the specs for i5 and i7 models. Also some benchmarks are out there. How can that be?

Comment: I saw that as well. Perhaps their higher end products are more popular.

Comment: It seems so. That means waiting till September. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find current evidence that Intel will even release Skyland i3's leak plans from 4 months ago were invalidated when their current tick-tock cycle was extended.

Comment: It's an i3, the only spec that'll be at all exciting is the price and you won't see that until it's released.

Comment: @Ramhound: I found [this](http://www.3dcenter.org/news/zweite-welle-skylake-desktop-prozessoren-erscheint-am-1-september) or [that](http://www.cpu-world.com/news_2015/2015072901_Core_i3_and_Pentium_Skylake_CPUs_to_launch_in_September.html).

Comment: @krowe: Many informations are available in advance with release date, core specs, price and so on. So why not for i3?

Comment: Because Intel has not even announced them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A month later the specs are now officially available on [ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/88394/6th-Generation-Intel-Core-i3-Processors#@Desktop).